# Module does not provide an export named 'default' - typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Issue:

dev console:

```
app.ts:21 Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/resources/js/plugins/register-global-components.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

building: npm run build:

```
Error: 'default' is not exported by resources/js/plugins/register-global-components.js, imported by resources/js/app.ts
```

register-global-components.ts

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import type { App } from 'vue'

export default function registerGlobalComponents (app: App): void {
    app.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
}
```

compiles down to:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var vue_fontawesome_1 = require("@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome");
function registerGlobalComponents(app) {
    app.component('font-awesome-icon', vue_fontawesome_1.FontAwesomeIcon);
}
exports.default = registerGlobalComponents;
```

app.ts

```
...

import registerGlobalComponents from './plugins/register-global-components'
```

tsconfig.ts

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // project options
        "lib": [
            "ESNext",
            "dom"
        ], // specifies which default set of type definitions to use ("DOM", "ES6", etc)
        "outDir": "lib", // .js (as well as .d.ts, .js.map, etc.) files will be emitted into this directory.,
        "removeComments": true, // Strips all comments from TypeScript files when converting into JavaScript- you rarely read compiled code so this saves space
        "target": "ES6", // Target environment. Most modern browsers support ES6, but you may want to set it to newer or older. (defaults to ES3)

        // Module resolution
        "baseUrl": "./", // Lets you set a base directory to resolve non-absolute module names.
        "esModuleInterop": true, // fixes some issues TS originally had with the ES6 spec where TypeScript treats CommonJS/AMD/UMD modules similar to ES6 module
        "moduleResolution": "node", // Pretty much always node for modern JS. Other option is "classic"
        "paths": {}, // A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the baseUrl

        // Source Map
        "sourceMap": true, // enables the use of source maps for debuggers and error reporting etc
        "sourceRoot": "/", // Specify the location where a debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of relative source locations.

        // Strict Checks
        "alwaysStrict": true, // Ensures that your files are parsed in the ECMAScript strict mode, and emit “use strict” for each source file.
        "allowUnreachableCode": false, // pick up dead code paths
        "noImplicitAny": true, // In some cases where no type annotations are present, TypeScript will fall back to a type of any for a variable when it cannot infer the type.
        "strictNullChecks": true, // When strictNullChecks is true, null and undefined have their own distinct types and you’ll get a type error if you try to use them where a concrete value is expected.

        // Linter Checks
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true, // accessing index must always check for undefined
        "noUnusedLocals": true, // Report errors on unused local variables.
        "noUnusedParameters": true // Report errors on unused parameters in functions
    },
    "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules/**/*"
    ]
}
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import ElementPlus from 'unplugin-element-plus/vite';


export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.ts',
            ]
        }),
        ElementPlus({
            // options
        }),
    ],
});
```

**What i have tried:**

Adding '.ts' to the path appears to solve the issue, though i don't believe is the correct solution as i get a typescript error "TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension."

```
import registerGlobalComponents from './plugins/register-global-components.ts' // added .ts
```

As far as i can see from searching stackoverflow is that my import and export statements are correct.

Not sure how to approach solving my issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing this problem but can you try the [allowSyntheticDefaultImport](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports) in your `tsconfig.json` file and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks. But didnt appear to help.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to repro this on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)? Please reply using "@vighnesh153" to notify me.